# Iterating over tuple in C++17/20

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17

Does anyone know of a good, clean way to iterate over a tuple in C++17 / 20?  Let's say we have a bit of code like this:

```
class Test
{
    public:
        Test( int x ) : x_(x) {};
        void Go() const { std::cout << "Hi!" << x_ << "\n" ; }
        int x_;
};
int main()
{
    std::tuple tplb{ Test{1} , Test{2} ,  Test{3} };
}
```

How could we iterate through the tuple and call the `Go()` method on each using the latest 17/20 features?

I know you could just have a vector of the object and then it works easily.  My goal with this is to be able to ha e a certain polymorphism without having to use virtual functions.

The idea would be to be able to have other object types in the tuple that support the same method.  If the method is present in each object then the code would compile and execute without having to use a base-class, virtuals, vtable, etc.

Is there some way perhaps with `std::apply` or `std::invoke` ?

Comment: @mistertribs that question asks about C++11, so it's now out of date.

Comment: @Brian - nevertheless several of the answers there apply to C++17.

Comment: Yeah, I think/hope that there are some new constructs in 17/21 that make this really elegant.  How cool would it be to have polymorphism like that enforced at compile time without virtuals?   And without five pages of hard-to-read-template work.

Comment: @mistertribs I agree, and in particular the answer by xskxzr explicitly targets C++17. But I don't think this question should be marked a duplicate of that one.

Comment: I did read that one - I hope there are some better c++17/21 solutions that allow the direct calling of a method on the objects in the tuple.

Comment: Would be nice if you could use range-based for loop but sadly it ain't so

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there some way perhaps with `std::apply` or `std::invoke` ?

`std::apply` fit the need indeed with fold expression:

```
std::tuple tplb{ Test{1} , Test{2} ,  Test{3} };

std::apply([](const auto&... tests){(tests.Go(), ...);}, tplb);
```

Here, we call method `Go()` for every type value of the `tuple`.

> The idea would be to be able to have other object types in the tuple that support the same method. If the method is present in each object then the code would compile and execute without having to use a base-class, virtuals, vtable, etc.

So above method works.
If you would go further and dispatch to different implementation according to type, you might use `overloaded` class from [std::visit's example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit):

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

auto f = overloaded {
        [](const Test& test) { test.Go(); },
        [](double d) { std::cout << d << ' '; },
        [](const std::string& s) { std::cout << s << ' '; },
    };
std::apply([&](const auto&... e){ (f(e), ...);}, my_tuple);
```

Comment: Ty, this is awesome!   Minor note, this: "std::apply([](const auto&... tests){(test.Go(), ...);}, tplb);"  needs to be "std::apply([](const auto&... tests) {(tests.Go(), ...); }, tplb);".

Comment: This lets me use a second class is completely unrelated but implements the "Go()" method.  So cool, ty again.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `using` declaration `Ts::operator()...`? Since the `Ts...` are being publicly derived from, isn't it unnecessary to adjust the accessibillity of the `operator()` member function?

Comment: It also seems that `f` should be invoked within the fold expression instead of `overloaded`. Currently, this attempts to derive from whatever is contained by `my_tuple`, followed by disregarding the constructed result.

Comment: @303: Without `using Ts::operator()...;`, call would be ambiguous.

Comment: Indeed, `f` should be used in `std::apply`, typo fixed.

Comment: Interestingly, someone posted a question about this particular peculiarity just a couple weeks ago which you also happened to have answered. More information about this ambiguity issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68678971/c-using-declaration-and-overload-paradigm

Answer (score 0):

Bit of `std::index_sequence` trickery is needed to access each member of the tuple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

class Test
{
    public:
        Test( int x ) : x_(x) {}; 
        void Go() const { std::cout << "Hi!" << x_ << "\n" ; } 
        int x_; 
};



template<typename F, typename T, std::size_t... Index>
void doStuffIndex(F&& action, T const& tup, std::index_sequence<Index...> const&)
{
    bool ignore[] = {((std::get<Index>(tup).*action)(), true)...};
}

template<typename F, typename... Obj>
void doStuff(F&& action, std::tuple<Obj...> const& tup)
{
    doStuffIndex(action, tup, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Obj)>());
}

int main()
{
    std::tuple<Test, Test, Test> tplb{ Test{1} , Test{2} ,  Test{3} };
    doStuff(&Test::Go, tplb);
}
```

Comment: Ty for this but not what I meant to ask.  Look at the answer below, that gets it exactly.  Notice that in your solution you still are referencing a specific Class::Method().  That restricts the ability to call the same method on a different class.  The answer below from Jarod42 nails it.