# How to iterate over non-const variables in C++?

Tags: c++, iteration, initializer-list

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct Obj {
    int i;
};

Obj a, b;

int main() {
    for(Obj& obj : {a, b}) {
        obj.i = 123;   
    }
}
```

This code does not compile because the values from the `initializer_list` `{a, b}` are taken as `const Obj&`, and cannot be bound to the non-const reference `obj`.

Is there a simple way to make a similar construct work, i.e. iterate over values that are in different variables, like `a` and `b` here.

Comment: @ruohola It was not specifically about using an initializer_list (like in this incorrect code), but if there is any other simple way in C++ to be able to iterate over objects that are in separate variables

Comment: And it is maybe not useful to try to perfectly follow modern C++ conventions like avoiding raw pointers and using `std::reference_wrapper` when it only makes the code more complicated; given that C++ itself is far from perfect

Comment: Okay, I understand :) Just thought that because all the well received answers solved the problem with `std::initalizer_list`, and that turned out to be the cleanest way to solve this, your question's intent could be drifted to be about `initializer_list` so that people searching for this kind of solution will find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It does not work because in `{a,b}` you are making a copy of `a` and `b`. One possible solution would be to make the loop variable a pointer, taking the addresses of `a` and `b`:

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct Obj {
    int i;
};

Obj a, b;

int main() {
    for(auto obj : {&a, &b}) {
        obj->i = 123;   
    }
}
```

See it [live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66ce858717dac524)

Note: it is generically better to use `auto`, as it could [avoid silent implicit conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32510343/8769985)

Comment: Would for(auto& obj: {&a,&b}) work here?  Or is that doing a conversion?

Comment: @Demolishun with ```auto& obj : {&a, &b}```, the variable ```obj``` is a *const* reference to a pointer. It makes sense to use pointer to references only when you want to modify the pointer itself, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823426/passing-references-to-pointers-in-c). In this case you would not be able to do so, because ```obj``` a ```const``` reference to the temporary pointers  ```&a``` and ```&b```. That said, in practive you would not notice any difference in the compiled code, check [here](https://godbolt.org/z/vFXyEH)

Answer (score 45):

The reason why that doesn't work is that the underlying elements of the [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) are copied from `a` and `b`, and are of type `const Obj`, so you are essentially trying to bind a constant value to a mutable reference.

One could try to fix this by using:

```
for (auto obj : {a, b}) {
    obj.i = 123;
}
```

but then would soon notice that the actual values of `i` in the objects `a` and `b` didn't change. The reason is that when using [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) here, the type of the loop variable `obj` will become `Obj`, so then you're just looping over copies of `a` and `b`.

The actual way this should be fixed is that you can use [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) (defined in the [`<functional>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional) header), to make the items in the initializer list be of type [`std::reference_wrapper<Obj>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper). That is implictly convertible to `Obj&`, so you can keep that as the type of the loop variable:

```
#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

struct Obj {
    int i;
};

Obj a, b;

int main()
{
    for (Obj& obj : {std::ref(a), std::ref(b)}) { 
        obj.i = 123;
    }
    std::cout << a.i << '\n';
    std::cout << b.i << '\n';
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 123
> 123
> ```

An alternative way to do the above would be to make the loop use `const auto&` and [`std::reference_wrapper<T>::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/get). We can use a constant reference here, because the `reference_wrapper` doesn't get altered, just the value it wraps does:

```
for (const auto& obj : {std::ref(a), std::ref(b)}) { 
    obj.get().i = 123;
}
```

but I think that, because using `auto` here forces the use of `.get()`, this is quite cumbersome and the former method is the preferable way to solve this.

---

It might seem to be more simple to do this by using raw pointers in the loop as @francesco did in his answer, but I have a habit of avoiding raw pointers as much as possible, and in this case I just believe that using references makes the code clearer and cleaner.

Comment: +1. While it maybe "looks" slightly more complicated, I deem this solution vastly superior compared to the accepted one, which not only changes semantics to pointers (which is "weird" if one expects objects), and thanks to using the _generically, maliciously better_  `auto` without an ampersand actually _copies_ pointers without that being obvious to the user. The `auto` keyword is such a dirty traitor. Copying pointers is admittedly "mostly harmless" but that's only a coincidence. Using actual references (with reference/object semantics) all through is just cleaner.

Answer (score 5):

If copying `a` and `b` is the desired behavior, you can use a temporary array rather than an initializer list:

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct Obj {
    int i;
} a, b;

int main() {
    typedef Obj obj_arr[];
    for(auto &obj : obj_arr{a, b}) {
        obj.i = 123;   
    }
}
```

This works even if `Obj` only has a move constructor.

Comment: If copying is the desired behaviour, you don't need a temporary array, just drop the reference: `for(auto obj : {a, b}) { obj.i = 123; }`

Comment: Yes; I've now added a note explaining why I still think it's relevant.

Answer (score -3):

A wee bit ugly but you can do this, since C++17:

```
#define APPLY_TUPLE(func, t) std::apply( [](auto&&... e) { ( func(e), ...); }, (t))

static void f(Obj& x)
{
    x.i = 123;
}

int main() 
{
    APPLY_TUPLE(f, std::tie(a, b));
}
```

It even would work if the objects are not all of the same type, by making `f` an overload set.  You can also have `f` be a (possibly overloaded) local lambda .   [Link to inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54641400/1505939).

The `std::tie` avoids the problem in the original code because it generates a tuple of references.  Unfortunately `std::begin` is not defined for tuples where all members are the same type (that would be nice!), so we can't use the ranged-based for-loop. But `std::apply` is the next layer of generalization up.

Comment: you could use std make array