# C++: using declaration and overload paradigm

Tags: c++, c++17, overloading

I was looking at [this page](https://www.cppstories.com/2018/09/visit-variants/) about "new" features of C++17.
In particular I understand almost all of the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

struct Fluid { };
struct LightItem { };
struct HeavyItem { };
struct FragileItem { };

template<class... Ts> struct overload : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overload(Ts...) -> overload<Ts...>;

int main() {
    std::variant<Fluid, LightItem, HeavyItem, FragileItem> package;

    std::visit(overload{
        [](Fluid& )       { std::cout << "fluid\n"; },
        [](LightItem& )   { std::cout << "light item\n"; },
        [](HeavyItem& )   { std::cout << "heavy item\n"; },
        [](FragileItem& ) { std::cout << "fragile\n"; }
    }, package);
}
```

What I do *not* understand is the

```
using Ts::operator()...;
```

inside de definition of struct `overload`. To my knowledge such use of `using` keyword is to ensure `operator()` to be `public`. But it seems to me already public, as far as lambdas are involved. So I would say it is redundant. I try to compile and execute with just

```
template<class... Ts> struct overload : Ts... { };
```

and everything works fine. Am I wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm, Clang accepts your program indeed but GCC rejects it. Removing `std::visit` and calling the instance of `overload` directly with a `Fluid` [yields](https://godbolt.org/z/sfMzze5x3) `error: request for member 'operator()' is ambiguous`. This might become a [tag:language-lawyer] question.

Comment: Is any part of this question about `std::visit`, overloading or paradigms? Isn't it just a question about [`using` declarations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`using` purpose is not only for changing accessibility, but to "resolve" ambiguity and/or unhide base methods.

See
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Member_function_definition

> otherwise, if the declaration sets in Bi and in C are different, the result is an ambiguous merge: the new lookup set of C has an invalid declaration and a union of the subobjects ealier merged into C and introduced from Bi. This invalid lookup set may not be an error if it is discarded later.

```
struct Base1
{
    void foo() {}
};

struct Base2
{
    void foo(int) {}
};

struct D : Base1, Base2
{
    // using Base1::foo; // Those would solve the ambiguity
    // using Base2::foo;

    void bar()
    {
        foo(); // ambiguous
    }
}

struct D2 : Base1
{
    // using Base1::foo; // This would unhide Base1::foo

    void foo(char) {} // hides Base1::foo

    void bar()
    {
        foo(); // wrong, find D2::foo(char)
    }
}
```

`using Ts::operator()...;` is then just the variadic syntax.